# Slow video performance with 4 monitors. What's the cause?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, performance, display, graphics-card

I recently installed another video card and added two more monitors to my work setup. Opening RDP windows and expanding the start menu cause the box to slow, mouse to jump and is a real productivity killer. Am I lacking the power necessary to drive the cards? Is there just increased processor load that is slowing me down?

- Dell Optiplex 755
- 265W Power supply
- Core 2 6600 (2.40 GHZ)
- 8GB RAM
- ATI Radeon HD 2400 Pro
- Nvidia GeForce 8400 GS
- Windows 7 x64

Comment: You'll need to supply more details on *both* graphics cards.

Comment: See - http://superuser.com/questions/92374/multiple-video-cards-on-windows-7