# Mixing AMD and NVIDIA graphics cards on one system

Tags: windows-7, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, amd-graphics-card, gpgpu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple video cards on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/92374/multiple-video-cards-on-windows-7)

I have a bit of a problem with graphics cards that I'd appreciate advice on.

On the one hand, I need an **ATI** graphics card, because a single Eyefinity card is perfect for running 6 monitors at 1080p via DisplayLink. It's awesome and though I know that I can replicate it with NVIDIA, it appears to be something that doesn't come out of the box.

On the other hand, I want an **NVIDIA** card because I want to do CUDA. This card will not drive any monitors, it's purely for floating-point calculations.

So my questions is: is it possible to mix the two on one system? Will there be any problems with drivers, motherboard, etc? And if not - what are my alternatives? (I.e., is it possible to drive 6 monitors *and* have a card that CUDA can be debugged on? Note that I won't consider business-grade graphics cards.)

**Update:** 6 different screens, Windows 7.

Comment: Six different screens of six clones?

Comment: What operating system? The answer is completely different for Windows 7 compared to XP.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Windows 7 officially supports multiple video cards with different drivers. CUDA should work so long as the video card has a monitor connected to it. (Or a dummy plug that makes it think it has a monitor connected to it. And actually I think that requirement has been fixed in newer drivers.)